# Switch layouts and get char without X11 by driver?

Tags: c, layout, keyboard, x11, encode

How to display different symbols for these layouts when the same keycode is pressed (let it be a qwerty keyboard)

For example, in the us layout, keycode 0x30 will display the symbol A/a depending on the parameters. But in the gr(greek) layout it will be the symbol α/Α depending on the parameters.

How to WITHOUT USING GUI LIKE X11/Wayland/etc. get vectorized keymap for this layout?

I found that bug, which, how I Understand telling about differences in keymaps beetween Console/X11 https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790955

Any universal way to print sequence of byte by pressing Keycode?